# On click how to keep workable LINK but disable #LINK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop, preventdefault

Ever we have used #link to go to our desired section on a page. Also use `animate`, `scrollTop()` to make the scroll smooth. But if the #link (Hash link) is on navigation menu then we have to put it like `example.com/pageslug/#sectionid` so that if we are on a separate page then it will redirect us to the specific page also section. But **this hides some text from that section** due to fixed navigation menu.

Again if we are using `animate` and `scrollTop()` there we have to use `e.preventDefault()` and if we use this, this will block page redirecting.

My question is how to make clickable link as well as well as block #link with `animate` and `scrollTop()`.

I don't know if this question proper or not, but I have tried/searched a lot but didn't got any solution so I came here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use animate function on targeting page, this function will run if url has section Id.
E.g. 
 Targeting url is

```
example.com/pageslug/#sectionid.
```

Write animate function on "example.com/pageslug" page with if condition to check is url contain section id. If section id is exist then animate function will execute to show content of that section.

It can solve you issue.

Comment: Thanks @Jony I have tried this by checking if url contains #link or section id, but before that jquery function execute #link works and the page scrolls to that section without any animation. And of course it will, because DOM works first and jQuery/Javascript functions after that.

Answer (score 0):

to disable workable link use href = "javascript:void(0)"
if you want to use animate and scrollTop use href = "javascript:void(0);"
if you want to go particular section in the page use href="#sectionid" in the hyperlink

Comment: Dear @Bharat, Thanks for you contribution. But Please read my query perfectly first. My concern is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys who have tried for me. I got a way to overcome this hurdle. but I am sure that it is not SEO Friendly.

If we make the URL as `example.com/pageslug?id=sectionid`

then the below function can help you.

```
$.urlParam = function(name){ // function to get the section id passed through URL
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}


var sectionid = $.urlParam('id');
if(sectionid != null) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+sectionid).offset().top - 100
    }, 1000);
}
```

But if any better answer and/or that is SEO friendly will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could using `event.preventDefault()`, when `a` tags with hash clicked.

```js
$(document).click('a[href*="#"]', function(e){
  var href = e.target.href;
  var id = href.substring(href.indexOf("#") + 1);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 60
  }, 1000);
})
```

https://codepen.io/1010543618/pen/XWWwVEd

Comment: PS: add 
```
margin-top: -40px;
padding-top: 40px;
```
can let selctions scroll to the `top: 40px` position

Comment: What about design? If I add a 40px padding-top, then the design will go wrong. Also, this will not work if I click on the link on another page as I asked if the link is on the navigation menu.

Comment: https://codepen.io/1010543618/pen/GRRbogE  This is a sample demo can let default hash go particular fragment with some 'padding'.